# missing ] after element list parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Executing that:

```
$.post(
"/url/to/method",
{ },
function(data){
    var obj2 = eval("("+$(data).children()+")");
    // OR var obj = $.evalJSON($($(data).children())); // Jquery-json
    $body = $("#AAA");
    $body.html(obj.fied);
},
 "xml"
);
```

while turn into a "missing ] after element list" (at row 5 or 6) error in firebug. The JSON output from method has been validated with jsonlint.com/

Probably is obvious but please I'm newbie around AJAX/JSON. Thanks

Comment: Don’t use `eval` to parse the JSON data. Use `JSON.parse` instead.

Comment: @Gumbo, Agreed JSON.parse can be found at http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: If you post the JSON, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: Also use http://www.jslint.com for validation! :)

Answer (score 14):

What is probably happening is that your $.post call is returning a JSON object already. jQuery will try to detect JSON automatically and parse it for you. When you call eval on a JSON object like this, you see this error. Sneaky! Just use the data object as is.

Comment: I had this issue, now using just the object I'm able to access to the JSON's members. Thanks.

Comment: I also was able to fix my issue with this answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) method, or be sure to include a space next to your parens before passing it to eval...

```
eval(" (" + data + ") ");
```

Comment: Using eval with spaces is still a no go (Same error). Using JSON.parse i go a strange error: text.replace is not a function, json2.js:445

Comment: Please post the JSON.  If it contains sensitive info, re-create the error using dummy data.  There is obviously something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing this in the .NET 2.0? If so try constructing your data into a query string rather than passing a JSON object.

Example:
var1=alma&var2=user

Where "var1" and "var2" are the names of the parameters that your webmethod expects. Pass this using the post.. Data: {querystring}
I ran into issues when passing JSON to webservice in 2.0.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that jQuery will try to figure out if the result is JSON and parse it automatically, but in this case data is already a JavaScript object and not a JSON string waiting to be parsed. So you can use this object as it is instead of using eval() and JSON.parse.